# How are regardless and regardlessly different?

Tags: difference, adverbs

Both regardless and regardlessly are adverbs, and Google said the latter is the adverb form of the former, but the former is an adverb. How are they different?

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regardless) (as well as several other major dictionaries) lists "regardless" as both an adverb and an adjective. That answers your question, doesn't it?

Comment: What difference is between them as adverbs?

Comment: I think that a dictionary could probably answer that  better than I could. Certainly more concisely.

Comment: No: "regardless" is best analysed as a preposition by virtue of being able to occur as head of an adjunct with no predicand. (please note @MarcInManhattan)

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious difference is that *regardlessly* is hardly ever used. The iWeb corpus has 691833 instances of *regardless* against 34 of *regardlessly*.

I don't think there is a systematic difference in their meaning.

Comment: I agree. I'm not sure the adverb "regardlessly" even exists. "Regardless" is best analysed as a preposition by virtue of being able to occur as head of an adjunct with no predicand.

Answer (score 0):

It is doubtful whether there actually is an adverb form "regardlessly".

"Regardless" is best analysed as a preposition by virtue of being able to occur as head of an adjunct with no predicand.

It selects "of" as head of its complement, though grammatically the complement is optional:

> *The project will go ahead,* *regardless* (*of any objections*).